# Estimate smart fee returns an error

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, fee-estimation

I am trying to get current fee for per transaction. So running command

```
bitcoin-cli estimatesmartfee 6
```

i am getting response lookl ike this

```
{
  "errors": [
    "Insufficient data or no feerate found"
  ],
  "blocks": 1
}
```

How ca I get real fee?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the node fully synced?

Comment: what do you mean saying fully synced? maybe no

Comment: Has it downloaded and verified all of the blocks? You can check with `$ bitcoin-cli getblockcount`

Comment: I got response - 1315692

Comment: looks like you're on testnet, there are 1414793 blocks so almost synced... https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/

Comment: yes I have on testnet!  its full node ? and why i cant to get fee ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the node is not fully synced the entire blockchain. If your node is not fully synced, then it hasn't parsed the latest blocks to see what a reasonable tx fee would be for the current market. If it's not fully synced, then it might try to estimate based on old transactions, which you don't want, since they could be much lower (and your tx will never confirm), or much higher (and you overpay in fees).

Comment: how can I sync ?

Comment: I assume it is syncing, is the number increasing when you check `$ bitcoin-cli getblockcount`? It takes a while to download and verify all of the blocks, sometimes days or weeks depending on your machine specs.

Comment: I just run this command and got response new number. but the command `estimatesmartfee` not working yet!

Comment: cool sounds like it's syncing, just need to be patient.